# Is django-filter FilterSet behavior consistent with native Django behavior for queries spanning multi-valued relationships?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter, graphene-django

I’m trying to query all unread messages for a user via the recipient model (i.e. each message has many recipients with a read property). The query works as expected when run with the model manager. For example:

```
Message.objects.filter(**{"recipients__user_id": 1, "recipients__read": False })
```

However, the query includes all messages the user received regardless of read status when run with FilterSet (using django-filter version 2.3.0).  For example:

```
MessageFilter(data={"recipients__user_id": "1", "recipients___read": False }).qs
```

Here’s the MessageFilter:

```
class MessageFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        exclude = ('deleted_at', )
        fields = ('chat_id', 'recipients__user_id', 'recipients__read', )
        filter_overrides = {
          # NOTE: enables support for querying pk rather than relay uuid
          models.ForeignKey: { 'filter_class': LocalIDFilter },
        }

    # NOTE: enables mapping from camelcase to snakecase
    order_by = OrderingFilter(fields=(('created_at', 'createdAt'),),)
```

Anyone know if my implementation is incorrect or if this is just desired library behavior (I couldn’t tell from the docs)? Also, any suggested workarounds would be appreciated. Aside from manually overriding the `qs` property on FilterSet, I'm not seeing any better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I've been poking around the source code more and it appears that the library's implementation is inconsistent (although that could be a deliberate design decision). But, I can achieve my desired filter by overwriting the filter_queryset method with the following:

```
class MessageFilter(FilterSet):
    
    ...
    
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{k: v for k, v in self.form.cleaned_data.items() if v is not None})
        assert isinstance(queryset, models.QuerySet), \
            "Expected '%s.%s' to return a QuerySet, but got a %s instead." \
            % (type(self).__name__, name, type(queryset).__name__)

        # NOTE: native implementation
        # for name, value in self.form.cleaned_data.items():
        #     queryset = self.filters[name].filter(queryset, value)
        #     assert isinstance(queryset, models.QuerySet), \
        #         "Expected '%s.%s' to return a QuerySet, but got a %s instead." \
        #         % (type(self).__name__, name, type(queryset).__name__)
        
        return queryset
```